# Cantor's theorem for presheaves?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Some years back (before MathOverflow was born), Tom Leinster [asked](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/01/2toposes.html#c014438) an interesting question at the $n$-Category Café which I don't recall ever seeing an answer for:

> Does there exist a category $C$ that admits an essentially surjective functor $F: C \to Set^{C^{op}}$?

Terminology: we say that a functor $F: C \to D$ is [essentially surjective](http://ncatlab.org:8080/nlab/show/essentially+surjective+functor) if every object $d$ of $D$ is isomorphic to some value $F(c)$. This is the good notion of surjectivity for the 2-category $Cat$, or at least one good notion.

As is well-known from categorical circles, the presheaf category $Set^{C^{op}}$ here plays a role of "power object" $P(C)$ that is usefully regarded as analogous to power sets in set theory or more generally in toposes. (For example, the Yoneda embedding $y_C: C \to Set^{C^{op}}$ plays a role analogous to the singleton mapping $\{-\}: S \to P(S)$ from set theory.) In fact Tom's question is embedded in a larger discussion of what one should mean by a '2-topos' -- see that discussion for more on the analogy.

So the question above is analogous to one that Cantor's theorem answers: can one have a set $S$ that maps onto its power set $S$? So the expected answer to the question is '**no**'. Note however that the standard diagonalization technique behind Cantor's theorem, as explained for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305282), doesn't apply in any obvious way since there is no general decent notion of diagonal map $C \to C \times C^{op}$.

Regarding foundational issues: I'll leave that up to you. :-) If you want me to impose a constraint, we might add the condition that $C$ is locally small, but note that we'll soon be leaving the land of local smallness anyway, since there is a [result](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/1-09abs.html) due to Freyd and Street that if also $Set^{C^{op}}$ is locally small, then $C$ is (equivalent to) a small category, and that would be a *huge* constraint that makes the question not so interesting.

Comment: The essence of Cantor's theorem is Lawvere's fixed-point theorem. Cantor's theorem works because the subobject classifier $\Omega$ has a fixed-point-free map, namely negation. Lawvere's fixed-point theorem works in any ccc (more or less), but it might be a bit harder to find a fixed-point free map on $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm not sure what Lawvere's fixed-point theorem is, but isn't the conclusion of Cantor's theorem the statement that Set has a fixed-point free map, namely the power set functor?

Comment: http://math.andrej.com/2007/04/08/on-a-proof-of-cantors-theorem/ is about Lawvere and Cantor. You're right about the powerset functor.

Comment: With Andrej, I also favor the Lawvere fixed-point theorem POV, which is why I linked to Yanofsky's paper (where I mentioned diagonalization).

Comment: @Theo: I think there are at least two problems with that argument, one being that at best you'll prove the statement with "essentially surjective" replaced by "surjective," but the other being that that to get a cartesian closed category of categories we need to restrict our attention to small categories, but then we disallow $\text{Set}$ itself...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am happy to use universes to assume that $Set$ and $C$, $C^{op}$ are small relative to the universe and small categories in that universe form something cartesian closed as a 1-category. (In other words, I am happy to work in a cartesian closed pretopos where we assume the existence of an internal topos object $S$.) But I don't see how you can really implement the rest of Lawvere's diagonalization argument, because of the issue of the opposite variance noted towards the end of my post.

Comment: Todd, isn't this obvious? Let us consider sets $1$ and $2$. There are functions $! \colon 2 \rightarrow 1$ and $j \colon 1 \rightarrow 2$. Therefore any function from objects $|\mathbb{C}^{op}| \rightarrow \{1, 2\}$ uniquely extends to a functor $\mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ lying over $!$ and $j$. Indeed, for the uniqueness, if $F, G \colon \mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ are two such functors with $F \approx G$, then for every $A \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $F(A) = G(A)$. (cont...)

Comment: This means that there are at least $2^{|\mathbb{C}|}$ non-isomorphic objects in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$, so by classical Cantor's argument there can be no essentially surjective functor  $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$.

Comment: @Michal: this is obvious if you require that $C$ is small. I think Todd wants to take $C$ to be $U$-small relative to a universe $U$ and then I guess things are okay if $\text{Set}$ is also the $U$-small version? I'm not very familiar with exactly what operations are and aren't allowed when working with universes, and in particular I don't know anything about forming $U$-small functor categories.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, you're right --- it's not obvious (i.e. what I have written is wrong), because there can be non-trivial compositions in $\mathbb{C}$. Yes, it is obvious if $\mathbb{C}$ is small (we can take the coproduct over the image of $F$, to get an object that by the assumption of essentially surjectivness would have a monomorphism from any object, what would lead to a contradiction). On the other hand, I don't think that there are foundational issues here --- what if we asked the same question about $\mathbf{FinSet}$ instead of $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: @Michal that would be like taking the "countable universe" $\mathbb{N}$, as a special case of some inaccessible $\lambda$. But restricting to finite categories $\mathbb{C}$, while I think to special a case to give a general proof, might be interesting...

Comment: @Michal:  If you don't require $C$ to be locally small, then $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$ can have the same number of objects (up to isomorphism) as $C$.  For instance, you can take $C$ to consist of an object with a descending sequence of retracts of length $Ord$.  Unfortunately, I can't see a way to turn this into a counterexample to the original question.  I also don't know whether this is possible with a locally small category.

Comment: You could also ask not for essentially surjectivity to fail, but some other 2-categorical analogue of for stronger notions of epimorphism, so there may be a vanilla epimorphism, but not, for instance, a descent morphism.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No such category exists.  My original argument for this assumed local smallness and is below the break; here is a simpler argument that does not require local smallness (though it does basically use my original argument in the special case $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{Set}$).

Let us take $\kappa$ to be an inaccessible cardinal and work with $V_\kappa$ as our universe, so the categories $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ we start with are classes in $V_\kappa$ (so $\mathbf{Set}$ is the category of sets in $V_\kappa$), and we only go outside $V_\kappa$ to form functor categories.  Suppose that there is an essentially surjective functor $\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$ and let $H$ be the associated functor $\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C}^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$.  I will obtain a contradiction by proving that there are $2^\kappa$ non-isomorphic objects of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$.

First of all, for every cardinal $\lambda<\kappa$, there is a constant presheaf $\lambda$ on $\mathbf{C}$, and so there is some object $A_\lambda$ with the property that $|H(A_\lambda,B)|=\lambda$ for all $B$.  Now fix any object $B$, considered as an object of $\mathbf{C}^{op}$.  Write $G(A)=H(A,B)$; then $G$ is a functor $\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$ with the property that $|G(A_\lambda)|=\lambda$ for all $\lambda$.  Consider $G$ as a functor $G^{op}:\mathbf{C}^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}^{op}$.  We can then compose $G^{op}$ with any functor $P:\mathbf{Set}^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ to get a new presheaf $PG^{op}$ on $\mathbf{C}$.  I claim that there are $2^\kappa$ choices of $P$ which give rise to non-isomorphic presheaves $PG^{op}$.

Indeed, since $G^{op}$ is essentially surjective, it suffices to give $2^\kappa$ different functors $P$ such that the induced maps $\{\text{cardinals }\lambda<\kappa\}\to\{\text{cardinals }\lambda<\kappa\}$ are distinct.  This is not difficult; for instance, it can be done by a variant of the "wedge of spheres" construction below (let $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{Set}$, $F(A)=|A|$, and instead of just taking a single copy of each sphere when constructing $T(Q)$, add enough spheres to change the cardinality of $T(Q)$ at $G(\alpha)$).

---

Let's work in the context of Grothendieck universes and require our categories to be locally small.  Then I claim that no such category exists.

Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal and let $V_\kappa$ be our base universe.  Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a locally small category.  Define an *exhaustion* of $\mathbf{C}$ to be an unbounded function $F:\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})\to \kappa$ such that if $B$ is a retract of $A$ then $F(B)\leq F(A)$.

First, I claim that if $\mathbf{C}$ has an exhaustion $F$, then $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$ has $2^\kappa$ non-isomorphic objects and hence there is no essentially surjective functor $\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$.  Let $1$ be the constant singleton presheaf on $\mathbf{C}$; let $*_B$ denote the unique element of $1(B)$ for all objects $B$.  Given an object $A$ of $\mathbf{C}$, let $S^A$ (the "$A$-sphere", by analogy with the case $\mathbf{C}=\Delta$) be the presheaf obtained from $1$ by freely adjoining an element of $S^A(A)$ whose image under every map $A\leftarrow B$ is $*_B$ for all $B$ such that $F(B)<F(A)$.  Since $A$ is not a retract of any such $B$, this new element of $S^A(A)$ will not be equal to $*_A$.

Now let $I\subseteq \kappa$ be the image of $F$ and choose a right inverse $G:I\to\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$ of $F$.   For each $Q\subset I$, define $T(Q)$ to be the colimit of the diagram consisting of the inclusions $1\to S^{G(\alpha)}$ for all $\alpha\in Q$.  This colimit exists because for any object $A$, $1\to S^{G(\alpha)}$ is an isomorphism at $A$ for all $\alpha>F(A)$, and hence this colimit is small at $A$.  We can determine the set $Q$ from the presheaf $T(Q)$ the same way you can determine the non-degenerate simplices of a simplicial set.  Thus the presheaves $T(Q)$ are all non-isomorphic.  Since there are $2^\kappa$ different values of $Q$, this proves the claim.

To prove the claimed theorem, it now suffices to show that any essentially large locally small category has an exhaustion.  Let $\mathbf{C}$ be an essentially large locally small category, and assume WLOG it is skeletal.  By essential largeness, let $f:\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})\to \kappa$ be a bijection.  By local smallness, each object of $\mathbf{C}$ has fewer than $\kappa$ other objects as retracts (since a retraction is determined by the associated idempotent endomorphism).  We can thus define $F:\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})\to \kappa$ by  $$F(A)=\sup \{f(B):B\text{ is a retract of }A\},$$
and this $F$ will be an exhaustion.

Comment: This construction is inspired by [an example I gave on another question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149161/finite-simplicial-sets#comment382832_149166) that shows there are uncountably many levelwise finite simplicial sets (thus proving this theorem for $\kappa=\aleph_0$ and $\mathbf{C}=\Delta$).

Comment: Beautiful! The intuition coming from simplicial sets is very helpful as well. +1 for now as I wait to see if anyone else wants to answer. Something about the focus on retractions is stylistically reminiscent of the Freyd-Street paper as well.

Comment: I feel like the central role of retractions in this argument is somehow the reason why the lack of a diagonal $\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C}^{op}$ is not a problem: if you just look at the retract preorder (which seems to be what really matters about $\mathbf{C}$ for these questions), then $\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C}^{op}$ looks the same as $\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C}$.  I'm not sure how to make this precise though.

Comment: Why can you assume that C has $\kappa$-many isomorphism classes? The discrete category with objects sets with cardinality smaller than or equipollent with some cardinal $\lambda \gt \kappa$ is locally small, but doesn't fit your proof... (the result is true, but for a different reason)

Comment: I'm only considering categories that are subclasses of the universe $V_\kappa$.

Comment: In retrospect, I'm not so sure that retractions are important to the argument anymore.  Now that I've come up with the new argument, it's clear that the "exhaustions" I was using were just shadows of a much more natural structure: an unbounded functor $G:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$ (the exhaustion then being $F(A)=|G(A)|$).  If you forget the functorial structure of $G$ and remember only $F$, you need to regain functoriality using representable functors, which is why my original argument required local smallness.

Comment: Ah, your more recent proof is both easier to follow and more general. I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @EricWofsey fair enough. But, and I'm afraid I'm going to be picky here, please state your assumptions in the answer and not just in comments that can get buried. So $Set = Set_{\lt\kappa}$ and, as you said, $C$ is contained in $V_\kappa$, and without loss of generality, $|Obj(C)| \not\lt \kappa$. I think this is a brilliant answer, in any case.

Comment: @EricWofsey it wasn't obvious to me that Todd implied such a thing, but then again, I didn't come up with the answer.

Comment: A wonderful answer! I wonder whether one can think of the correspondence $A \mapsto S^A$ as of a certain "rectification" of the Yoneda embedding as the "2-topos" analogue of the singleton mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize in advance for my probable mistake's.

I did a proof for a small category.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ any category, pose $\mathcal{C}^>:=Fun(\mathcal{C}, Set)$. If $\mathcal{C}$ has only one object $\ast$, let $G$ the monoid of its morphisms, then a presheaf $P\in \mathcal{C}^>$ is a $G^{op}$-Set  $G\times S_P\to S_P$.
Of course there are $G^{op}$-Set's of any cardinality, then cannot exist a essentially surjective small family of functor $F_i: \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}^>\ i\in I$ (i.e. $\forall P\in \mathcal{C}^>\ \exists i\in I, X\in \mathcal{C}: F_i(X)\cong P$).
Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ a (small) **set of object**, and  $F: \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}^>$ is a essentially surjective functor, make $\widetilde{\mathcal{C}}$  identifying in $\mathcal{C}$  all object in only one $\ast$ and let $q: \mathcal{C}\to \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}$ the natural functor quotient. Let $P\in \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}^>$ see as a $G^{op}$-Set as above. Let $X_P\in \mathcal{C}$ with a isomorphism $\phi: F(X)\cong P\circ q$, then $F(X_P)$ is a family of set $F(X_P)(Y)\ Y\in \mathcal{C}$ with isomorphism's $\phi_Y: F(X_P)(Y)\cong S_{P}$  and this system is coherent with the morphism's  $F(X_P)(f): F(X_P)(Y)\to F(X_P)(Z)$ for $f: Z\to Y$ and the associate $q(f): \ast\to\ast$, and each of this morphism has a  "translate" $f_{X_P}:= {\phi_{X_P}}^{-1}\circ \phi_Z\circ F(f)\circ {\phi_Y}^{-1}\circ \phi_{X_P}$ as endomorphism of $F(X_P)(X_P)$, and this make $F(X)_P(X_P)$ a $G^{op}$-Set, with a $G^{op}$-coherent isomorphism $F(X_P)(X_P)\cong S_P$ i.e. a presheaf $\tilde{F}_P: \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}\to \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}^> $.

If $\mathcal{C}$ **is small**  the couple's $(F(X)(X), \theta)$ where $X\in\mathcal{C}$ and $\theta$ is a $G^{op}$-action on $F(X)(X)$ form a (small) set, and this set contain any of the $G^{op}$-set $F(X_P)(X_P)$. Then we have a small family $\tilde{F}_i: \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}\to \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}^>\ X\in\mathcal{C}\ i\in I$ essentially surjective (absurd).

Comment: I don't consider the small category case interesting, since we can just consider constant presheaves which form an essentially large class.